# Flutter firebase app runs perfect in web but fails on android. Sign in does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

My app has two pages signIn and home...these classes are backed with database classes and authentication classes .The full todo app works on my chrome but the sign in does not work on android showing error in gesture detector
Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?but even on looking at various docs making changes i found no solution
home:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:noteit/views/home.dart';
import 'package:noteit/views/signin.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() {
  
   runApp(MyApp());
  
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'NoteIt',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        //scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff8C93A8),
      ),
      home:SignIn()
      //myhome(userName: "Rick", userEmail:"bjab",userimage: "",)
    );
  }
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       
        title: Text("Hey"),
      ),
     
       );
  }
```

build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.noteit"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
       
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
 
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

authorization class where all firebase works take place:

```
class AuthService{
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  Future<User?> SignInwithgoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    
   

    final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

    final GoogleSignInAccount? _googleSignInAccount =
        await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await _googleSignInAccount!.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    final UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    final User? userDetails = result.user;
    

    if (result == null) {
    }
     else {
        Map<String,dynamic> userMap = {
     "userName": userDetails!.displayName,
       "email": userDetails.email
      };
        DatabaseServices().uploadUserInfo(userDetails.uid, userMap);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>myhome(
       userEmail: userDetails.email!,
       userName: userDetails.displayName!,
       userimage:userDetails.photoURL!,
      )
      ));

      

     
     }
     return userDetails;


  }
  
  Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>SignIn()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps detailed here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Comment: can you tell us the exact error that you are getting please ?